# ReactJS: adding my own props to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible (or even a good idea) to add my own props to another React component, like:

```
<SomeCustomComponent myOwnParam={handler}>
```

Comment: Possible, yes, but if you're not in control of it, the component won't use the custom prop you're passing.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this? What is `SomeCustomComponent` supposed to do with `myOwnParam`?

Comment: I'm trying to extend it with my own functionality...maybe I'm thinking something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25720595/extending-react-js-components

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by Tyrsius, it really depends on the implementation of `SomeCustomComponent`.  If the component does not use the `myOwnParam` prop anywhere, passing it won't accomplish anything.  On the other hand, some React components might use JSX spread attributes to reference props not directly enumerated in the code.

As an example, the following implementation of `SomeCustomComponent` would pass your `myOwnParam` prop down to its child `div`:

```
class SomeCustomComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    var {customComponentProp, ...other } = this.props;
    return (
      <div customComponentProp={customComponentProp} {...other}></div>
    );
  }
}
```

So again, it depends on the implementation of `SomeCustomComponent` what will happen.

See Transferring Props documentation for more details: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html

Answer (score 2):

This won't cause an error, but unless `SomeCustomComponent` is looking for this prop nothing will be done with it. It is *possible* for a component to loop over its props, so this *could* be a usable strategy, but I am not sure what you would do with it. You couldn't define anything but iteration logic over properties that you don't know in advance.